# Sorting doesn't work for my table header icons, what can I do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

In the code below, I tried creating a simple student grade book with a dynamic div which appears by pressing the show grades button. The button is dynamically created and appears in the table next to the student names. As you can see, the font awesome sorting icons in the table header don't work properly and I don't know where I went wrong with the code. Code snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    "use strict";
    // student list
    var studentsList = [{
            name: "Peter",
            grades: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: "Stark",
            grades: [10, 10, 10, 9, 7],
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: "Thanos",
            grades: [3, 5, 9, 7, 10],
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: "Hulk",
            grades: [2, 2, 2, 2, 10],
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: "Thor",
            grades: [10, 5, 9, 4, 10],
            selected: false
        }
    ];

    // prevent enter from submitting/refreshing
    $("#namesInput").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#addStudentBtn").click();
        }
    });

    //variables
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("namesInput");
    var addStudentBtn = document.getElementById("addStudentBtn");
    var newIndex;
    var gradesInput = document.getElementById("gradesInput");
    var gradesTableBody = document.getElementById("gradesTableBody");
    var addGradesBtn = document.getElementById("addGradesBtn");
    var gradesHeader = document.getElementById("gradesHeader");
    var oldIndex;
    var studentsTableBody = document.getElementById("studentsTableBody");
    var gradesWrapper = document.getElementById("gradesWrapper");
    var hideGradesBtn = document.getElementById("hideGradesBtn");
    var sortGradesDown = document.getElementById("sortGradesDown");
    var sortGradesUp = document.getElementById("sortGradesUp");
    var sortAverageUp = document.getElementById("sortAverageUp");
    var sortAverageDown = document.getElementById("sortAverageDown");
    var sortingNaming;

    //events
    addStudentBtn.addEventListener("click", studentNameInput);
    addGradesBtn.addEventListener("click", studentGradesInput);
    studentsTableBody.addEventListener("click", studentNameInput);
    hideGradesBtn.addEventListener("click", hideGrades);
    sortGradesDown.addEventListener("click", studentGradesInput);
    sortAverageDown.addEventListener("click", studentNameInput);
    sortGradesUp.addEventListener("click", studentGradesInput);
    sortAverageUp.addEventListener("click", studentNameInput);



    //functions
    function drawStudentTable() {
        var tableBody = document.getElementById("studentsTableBody");
        var tableData = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < studentsList.length; i++) {
            tableData += `
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>${studentsList[i].name}</td>
        <td>${averageGrade(studentsList[i].grades)}</td>
        <td><button data-index ="${i}" data-id ="showGrades">Show grades</button></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        `;
        }
        tableBody.innerHTML = tableData;
    }
    drawStudentTable(studentsList);


    function averageGrade(array) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sum += parseInt(array[i], 10);
        }
        var average = (sum / array.length).toFixed(2);
        average = Number(average);
        return average;
    }


    function addStudent() {
        var newStudent = {
            name: nameInput.value,
            grades: [],
            selected: false,
        }
        studentsList.push(newStudent);
        nameInput.value = "";
    }

    function selectStudent(event) {
        oldIndex = newIndex;
        newIndex = Number(event.target.dataset.index);
        studentsList[newIndex].selected = true;
        if (oldIndex || oldIndex == 0) {
            studentsList[oldIndex].selected = false;
        }
    }

    function studentNameInput(event) {
        if (nameInput.value && event.target.id == "addStudentBtn") {
            addStudent();
            drawStudentTable();
        } else if (event.target.dataset.id == "showGrades") {
            selectStudent(event)
            showGrades();
            drawGradesTable();
        } else if (event.currentTarget.dataset.id == "sortBtn") {
            drawStudentTable();
            sortingOrder(event);
            sortingAverageGrades();
        }
    }

    function addGrade() {
        if (gradesInput.value <= 10) {
            var newGrade = Number(gradesInput.value);
            newGrade = Number(newGrade.toFixed(2));
            var grades = studentsList[newIndex].grades;
            grades.push(newGrade);
            gradesInput.value = "";
        } else
            alert("Grade is not correctly inserted!");
    }

    function drawGradesTable() {
        var grades = studentsList[newIndex].grades;
        gradesTableBody.innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            gradesTableBody.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
            <td>${grades[i]}</td>
            </tr>
            `;
        }
    }

    function showGrades() {
        gradesHeader.innerHTML = studentsList[newIndex].name;
        gradesInput.value = "";
        gradesWrapper.classList.remove("hidden");
        gradesWrapper.classList.add("float");
        studentsWrapper.classList.add("float");
    }

    function hideGrades() {
        gradesWrapper.classList.add("hidden");
        studentsWrapper.classList.remove("float");
        gradesInput.value = "";

    }

    function studentGradesInput(event) {
        if (gradesInput.value && event.target.id == "addGradesBtn") {
            addGrade();
            drawStudentTable();
            drawGradesTable();
        } else if (event.target.dataset.id == "showGrades") {
            selectStudent(event)
            drawGradesTable();
            showGrades();
        } else if (event.target.id == "hideGradesBtn") {
            hideGrades();
        } else if (event.currentTarget.dataset.id == "sortBtn") {
            drawGradesTable();
            sortingOrder(event);
            sortingGrades();
        }
    }

    function sortingOrder(event) {
        if (event.target.id == "sortGradesDown" || event.target.id == "sortAverageDown") {
            sortingNaming = "descending";
        } else if (event.target.id == "sortGradesUp" || event.target.id == "sortAverageUp") {
            sortingNaming = "ascending";
        }
    }

    function sortingAverageGrades() {
        var grades = studentsList[newIndex].grades;
        if (sortingNaming == "ascending") {
            grades.sort((a, b) => a - b);
        } else if (sortingNaming == "descending") {
            grades.sort((a, b) => b - a);
        }
    }


    function sortingGrades() {
        if (sortingNaming == "ascending") {
            studentsList.sort(function (a, b) {
                return averageGrade(a.grades) - averageGrade(b.grades);
            });
        } else if (sortingNaming == "descending") {
            studentsList.sort(function (a, b) {
                return averageGrade(b.grades) - averageGrade(a.grades);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}


body {
    min-width:900px;
    height:100%;

}

#studentsWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100em;
    margin-bottom: -100em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightseagreen;

}
h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

td {
    height: 40px;
}

table {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top:50px;
}
th {
    text-align: center;
    padding:0.3em;
    font-size: 25px;

}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.float {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#gradesWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100em;
    margin-bottom: -100em;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    background-color: lightgreen;


}

#hideGradesBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 1em;
}

input{
border-radius: 50px;
border:none;
height: 30px;
width: 150px;
}


button {
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    border:none;
    height: 30px;
}
button:hover {
    color:white;
    background-color: rgb(27, 145, 139);
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Catalog de note">
    <meta name="author" content="Adelina Lipsa">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Catalog de note</title>
    <link href="catalog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2926c10e78.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="studentsWrapper">
        <h2><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> Students list </h2>
        <div class="input-space">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="namesInput">
            <button id="addStudentBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add student</button>
        </div>
        <table id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Average grade</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><button id="sortAverageDown" data-id="sortBtn" class="sortBtn"><i
                                class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button><button id="sortAverageUp"
                            data-id="sortBtn" class="sortBtn"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-up"></i></button>
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="studentsTableBody"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="gradesWrapper" class="hidden">
        <button id="hideGradesBtn">Hide grades</button>
        <h2 id="gradesHeader"></h2>
        <div class="grades-space">
            <input type="number" id="gradesInput" autocomplete="off" min="1" max="10">
            <button id="addGradesBtn">Add grade</button>
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Grades</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <button id="sortGradesDown" data-id="sortBtn" class="sortBtn"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button><button id="sortGradesUp" data-id="sortBtn" class="sortBtn"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-up"></i></button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="gradesTableBody"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm open to another sorting method also

Comment: What should be the benefit of using `toFixed()` and then converting the result back to number?